# How to sign in azure ad from node.js script(without browser flow)

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I want to CALL api which needs azure ad authentication.
I succeeded azure ad authentication from browser sign in, but I also want to access to api from script.
How can I sign in azure without browser sign in flow?

#### additional question.

I succeeded server-to-server authentication flow, but Is there way to call api as an "azure ad account" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement client credential flow in node.js which will not require browser.

1. Please find document which can help you in adding [Azure Active Directory modules for Node.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/activedirectory?view=azure-node-latest)
2. Please find code sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs) which  illustrates server-to-server authentication via client credentials flow.

Comment: I succeeded server-to-server authentication. However, it is better if I could call api as an azure ad account from script without browser flow. Can I do it ?

Comment: Do you mean login with user login?? You can use [Device-code-flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code) which will also does not require browser and the user need to log in.Please let me know if it helps. :)

Comment: Please let me know if you still need any help.

Comment: It would be what I wanted, so I'll try your link, but now I have another task ><.  Thank you!